# DbUtils: For Development environment

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, databricks-connect

We have created secrets and scopes in datababricks and we are using dbUtils to access those secrets and scopes.

```
dbUtils.getSecret(SCOPE,KEY)
```

Unfortunately, this dbUtils function is not working on development environment, so I need advice on how to access this and what are the best possible alternative to get rid of this ?

Comment: are you using databricks-connect for development?

Comment: @AlexOtt - Yes I am using databricks-connect

Answer (score 0):

If you use Databricks Connect, then secrets API is disabled by default, but it could be enabled on request. It's described in the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#enable-dbutilssecretsget):

> Because of security restrictions, the ability to call `dbutils.secrets.get` is disabled by default. **Contact Databricks support to enable this feature for your workspace**.

But really, for tests it should be mocked, and it should be only really used when you're debugging something.